# Reduce a variable for a set time

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm trying to reduce a variable by 5, Print the new variable, and then after X amount of time increase the variable again and print the variable. Its for a small Text based game where you send some people away and they wont come back for a set amount of time.

```
import time

TimeReturned = time.time() + 5
Survivors = 10

Test = raw_input("Run Script?")
if Test == "Yes":
    print Survivors
    if TimeReturned > time.time():
        Survivors -= 5
        print Survivors
    Survivors += 5
    print Survivors
```

All I get as the output is 10, 5, 10 straight away, it doesn't delay the time at all. This is my first question so sorry if it is vague.

1. What have I done wrong that is causing this code to return the Variables instantly?
2. If I want to do other things in the script such as send the remaining Survivors away as well is it possible whilst this script is running or would I need to wait the 5 seconds?

Thanks for your patience:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to make your script wait, use [`time.sleep(num_seconds)`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.sleep). [`time.time()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.time) just returns what the current time is; it doesn't make anything wait at all.

It's possible to have some code be sleeping yet have other code running at the same time, doing something else. To do that, you have to use [threads](http://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html), though, which take some time getting used to. Perhaps [this tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_multithreading.htm) would be of use.

EDIT: Oh it's also possible to do this without threads, but you have to keep track of your variables carefully. You messed up your math a bit. Say that when time.time() was 1000 your code ran. Then `TimeReturned` is 1005. Say it took 1 second for the user to type in `Yes`. Then the `if TimeReturned > time.time()` checks `if 1005 > 1001`, which is True. What you really wanted to check is `if time.time() > TimeReturned` - if the current time is later than `TimeReturned`.

Also your script is not interactive so it would be hard to see any progress. Try running this script:

```
import time

survivors = 15
survivor_return_seconds = 10.0
time_survivors_left = None

while True:
    action = raw_input("Type 'x' to make survivors leave, ENTER to see how many are left: ")

    #check if survivors returned
    if time_survivors_left is not None:
        if time.time() >= time_survivors_left + survivor_return_seconds:
            survivors += 5
            time_survivors_left = None
            print "Survivors came back!"

    if action == 'x':
        if time_survivors_left is not None:
            print "Survivors already left! Wait a bit!"
        else:
            survivors -= 5
            time_survivors_left = time.time()

    print "There are %s survivors left." % (survivors,)
    if time_survivors_left is not None:
        print "5 survivors will return in %.2fs" % (
            time_survivors_left + survivor_return_seconds - time.time())
```

Example output:

```
Type 'x' to make survivors leave, ENTER to see how many are left: 
There are 15 survivors left.
Type 'x' to make survivors leave, ENTER to see how many are left: 
There are 15 survivors left.
Type 'x' to make survivors leave, ENTER to see how many are left: x
There are 10 survivors left.
5 survivors will return in 9.99s
Type 'x' to make survivors leave, ENTER to see how many are left: 
There are 10 survivors left.
5 survivors will return in 9.05s
Type 'x' to make survivors leave, ENTER to see how many are left: 
There are 10 survivors left.
5 survivors will return in 7.66s
Type 'x' to make survivors leave, ENTER to see how many are left: 
There are 10 survivors left.
5 survivors will return in 6.45s
Type 'x' to make survivors leave, ENTER to see how many are left: x
Survivors already left! Wait a bit!
There are 10 survivors left.
5 survivors will return in 5.73s
Type 'x' to make survivors leave, ENTER to see how many are left: 
There are 10 survivors left.
5 survivors will return in 4.15s
Type 'x' to make survivors leave, ENTER to see how many are left: 
There are 10 survivors left.
5 survivors will return in 2.90s
Type 'x' to make survivors leave, ENTER to see how many are left: 
There are 10 survivors left.
5 survivors will return in 1.72s
Type 'x' to make survivors leave, ENTER to see how many are left: 
There are 10 survivors left.
5 survivors will return in 0.48s
Type 'x' to make survivors leave, ENTER to see how many are left: 
Survivors came back!
There are 15 survivors left.
Type 'x' to make survivors leave, ENTER to see how many are left: 
There are 15 survivors left.
Type 'x' to make survivors leave, ENTER to see how many are left:
```

Comment: Ok but wont that make the whole script stop for (num_seconds)? I plan to make the Time that Survivors is decreased by roughly 20*60 Seconds so making the script itself stop for that long would kill me. If possible id like it to be able to do other things whilst the time.sleep(20*60) is running.

Comment: @user2146277: It would yeah. You can do it without sleeping, check out my update. You just got the math backwards

Comment: That script works wonders, I also read up on the tutorial and a few others and understand more of what is going on in threads as well.
To make it so i can send multiple waves of Survivors at the same time would it be possible, or would that best be done in threads?

Thanks for all your help:)

Comment: @user2146277: if you're ok with nothing happening until the user types something in, then you can just use `raw_input` and process all the events then. but that means if something has to happen in 5 seconds and the user takes 3 minutes to type something in, then they won't see it till then. if you want things to happen simultaneously then you will have to use threads

Comment: Thank you very much for all your help:) Ill experiment with using raw_input and seeing if it works, if it doesnt then ill use threads:) Thanks

Answer (score 0):

well... you didn't do anything to make the script halt and wait.

```
if TimeReturned > time.time():
```

this just checks whether the condition is true and procedes accordingly, it doesnt instruct anyone to wait.

you should use the `time.sleep(secs)` function to halt the execution of the code for the desired amount of time.

notice though, that  during the sleep time, nothing is executed. so, if you want some background processes to keep running and only those guys you mentioned to wait, you should run that part of the script in it's own thread.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know how to create threads (Not that I'm aware of at least.) I'm new to Python and programming and decided if I started a project I'd be able to learn things that are needed whilst building it, It has worked so far but trying to do this part has just caused problems. I shall look it up:) Thank you:) Claudiu has provided me a link to threads which should help:)

Answer (score 0):

You could do what you want with a `Timer`.  It runs for the specified number of seconds, then executes the function you specify.  A `Timer` is just a simple way of using a second thread, which is why it is in the `threading` module.

```
from threading import Timer
import time

Survivors = 10

def increase_survivors():
    global Survivors
    Survivors += 5

# start execution
print Survivors
Survivors -= 5

t = Timer(5, increase_survivors)
t.start()
for i in range(10):
    print Survivors
    time.sleep(1)
```

The last bit is just showing how it works.  There's probably a better way to manage your variables than that `global` statement though - I'm sure I'll get some suggestions.

Comment: Wont that just increase Survivors by 5 after the Timer runs for 5 seconds making Survivors = 15?

Comment: I missed the first bit where you start by reducing the survivors.  Anyway, the important part is the waiting before changing the variable, no?